# Google Sheets Function to auto select from table using multiple criteria

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I'm making a quote generating google sheet.  As part of quote generation I have a few different quote groups based on the size of product.  I've made a table outlining the groups, and the associated W and H for each. (cells A1:D9 in the image)

I'm trying to find the most effective way, that when I enter specific data into the space provided (G2 for width, and G3 for height) that G4 will automatically populate based on the table data ranges and if the provided data is outside of the table data to also populate in that space.

[image: google sheet data]

For example, if someone enters width(g2): 7, Height(g3): 1.5, that G4 will populate with "B".  Those numbers aren't explicitly in the group data, but fall within a group. Technically B, D and E would qualify, but for quoting purposes, we'd use B. The groups are assigned (A-H) based on their heights (which I cannot change as the groups are provided by a third party vendor), but not necessarily their cost.  I want to add a third column as well, ranking the groups ultimately by cost and selecting the most cost effective, so any input there would be amazing.

I know I could write lists of IF and IFS etc (which I've tried), however that would get extremely cumbersome very quickly. And I'm nearly positive a built in function exists to help out with this, but I don't even know what function to search for.

If you happen to have something exact that I can copy and paste, then awesome, but even if you can give me a place to start my search I'd be gratefully.

Answer (score 0):

One method you could use to achieve this would be this formula:

`=INDEX(A2:D, MATCH(MIN(SQRT((C2:C-G2)^2 + (D2:D-G3)^2)), SQRT((C2:C-G2)^2 + (D2:D-G3)^2), 0), 1)`

The idea behind it is we calculate the distance between each pair of values, we then find the minimum distance in order to get the closest matching pair or values. If there is a tie, it is the first occurrence in the array.

However it was not expressed if they can be greater than or less than.

As for factoring expenses there is not a way to achieve that without hard input. How can a computer decide if option 2 is better than option 1 because it is cheaper without telling it the parameters and limits?

**Update 1:**

If you would like to easily tell when a match is exact or not, you could append an `*` to the result. Meaning in your example the result would be `B*` as it is the closest match and there was not an exact match.

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A, MATCH(G2&G3, C2:C&D2:D, 0)), INDEX(A2:A, MATCH(MIN(SQRT((C2:C-G2)^2 + (D2:D-G3)^2)), SQRT((C2:C-G2)^2 + (D2:D-G3)^2), 0)) & "*")`

Comment: thanks for your anwser. If you assume that column E listed the pricing as a scale, 1 cheapest, to 8 most pricey, how would that factor into what you've shared?

Comment: It's hard to say, as without telling the formula where your limits are it's impossible to know if having a very close match with a cost scale of 1 is better than an exact match of a cost scale of 2. Your best bet may be to add a parameter for cost scale. Such that if you declare you want the cost to be a value of 4 it will account for all 3 values and find the closest match to all 3.

Comment: Or you could get very deep down a math hole and add the cost scale to the distance between matches. Something inversely porportional. For example if the total distance between the closest match is .5 and the cost is a 2 then the total is 2.5, if the next best options distance is 1 and the cost is 1 then the total is 2. Making option 2 slightly better based on cost even though it is the 2nd closest match.  This would entirely be based on your preference and a magic ratio number of exactly how weighted cost is to you. I hope this makes sense.